# scale span width 100% of parent td

Tags: html, email

I'm working on an email template, so I'm limited with `div`, and CSS. Some email clients do not handle `div` and CSS. I have to use tables instead.

I have a `td`, in that `td` I need a title text with colored background at 100% width of `td`.

**Here is my code, that is not working:**

```html
<td width="50%" valign="top" style="border: solid 2px #3c3141; border-width: 6px 2px 4px 0px; border-top-left-radius: 30px; border-bottom-right-radius: 30px; border-left: none; background-color: #f1e4e7; margin: 0px; padding: 20px; text-align: center;">
<span style="background-color: #f5434f; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; width: 100%;">
  <strong>Termek nev</strong>
  </span><br>
  <span>
    <br>ide jon a szoveg
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Add display:block, to span.

Comment: Make span display block

Comment: I do not know if display: block is working on all email clients

Comment: Its work if not replace with inline-block

Comment: Any email client that can handle a `td` element with a `style=…` attribute can handle `div` in the same manner.  I'm pretty sure most of those (if not all) can also handle a `style` element as well, but you can also use a table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a width for an inline element like `span`.  Either use a block element like `div` or `p` or else force the `span` to display as a block using `display:block` as follows:

```
<td width="50%" valign="top" style="border: solid 2px #3c3141; border-width: 6px 2px 4px 0px; border-top-left-radius: 30px; border-bottom-right-radius: 30px; border-left: none; background-color: #f1e4e7; margin: 0px; padding: 20px; text-align: center;">
<span style="background-color: #f5434f; color: #ffffff; padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; width: 100%; display:block">
  <strong>Termek nev</strong>
  </span><br>
  <span>
    <br>ide jon a szoveg
  </span>
</td>
```